# How to import a row of a datatable from a SQL database connection

Tags: sql, select, datatable

I am trying to import single rows out of a DataTable from a SQL Database connection.
The database connection and everything else works, but I only found 'data = select(conn,selectquery)' as a possible statement to extract data.

```
username='';
password='';
status = testConnection(opts,username,password);
saveAsJDBCDataSource(opts);

datasource='';
conn = database(datasource,username,password);

query1=strcat("select row from DataTable");

query2 = strcat("SELECT * FROM DataTable ", ...
"WHERE filename = xxx");


data = table2array(fetch(conn,query1))
```

I tried different prepared statements but it gives me the error: "no such column"
... of course not I want to select a row :D

The other option is to read the whole DataTable with the statement "data = sqlread(conn,tablename);" but at some point, the data table is too big and I get a **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** error

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first issue: it might be a problem with the WHERE-Statement that gives the error "no such column". You have to specify the attribute condition with `''`

```
    query2 = strcat("SELECT * FROM DataTable ", ... "WHERE filename = 'xxx'");
```

Comment: Thanks it helped to fix that error but I need definitly a different statement because SELECT only returns column data (MATLAB Help: "...select returns column data in native data types....") but I want to import rows